# Autodesk Forge - how to use the new Model Derivative IFC pipeline?

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

I'm working with autodesk forge, because I have a project for the University, but I have a small problem now.

I read that the IFC Model Derivative processor is currently based on the Navisworks importer, but a better implementation is [using Revit instead](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change). As I work mostly with IFC Files this could make a big difference.

I made a small application with the help of the [forge-apis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis) npm package, which enables me to easily integrate the Forge APIs.

The Problem is that I don't see an option to use the new Model Derivative IFC pipeline. Is there a way to implement it in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this point, you'll need to make requests (e.g. using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package). When we completely move to Revit pipeline you can resume with the forge-api package.